# Android build fails after flavor is added

Tags: react-native

I have a react native application ready for the release, after following the android documentation and have added flavors to the product

```
flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
    free {
        dimension "version"
        applicationId 'com.my-app.free'
    }
}
```

**The command `react-native run-android` fails the gradle build with the following error:**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-appboy-sdk:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;

Considerations

- If I comment the flavor in the gradle file the command runs without any problem.
- Even with this error, I can assemble the apk without any errors using the command `./gradlew assembleRelease`.
- I can run the app using the android studio run configuration without any errors, this seems to be related to adding flavors and running with the react-native command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please add below code in your android/build.gradle file, hope it will help you:

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}
```

Also try below command if above not working:

```
react-native run-android --variant=developmentDebug
```

Comment: Thanks for writing, unfortunately the problem still persists

Comment: After reviewing this problem I found [this article](https://medium.com/@ywongcode/building-multiple-versions-of-a-react-native-app-4361252ddde5) that clarifies that after adding product flavors you can't build your react native app without specifying a build variant anymore.  as you pointed out, using a variante will solve the problem.... then another problem appears which a known bug described in the article, but you can run the project using android studio to workaround it.